# ayuda como agregar y quitar div hijo con botones en reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, html5, reactjs

Buen día.
Estoy realizando una pagina web con react, hay un div padre en donde tengo dos botones y cada uno cambia cada div hijo ahí el ejemplo:

[image: ejemplo]

en mi código:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import Facial from "../FacialRecognition"
import ObjectD from "../ObjectDetection"
import Form from "../Form"
import Footer from "../footer"
import Nav from "./Nav"

class Technologies extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <div className="section-66">
          <div className="div-block-311">
            <div className="div-block-113">
              <p className="paragraph-14 title">
                Spot technologies. <b>intelligence artificial made simple</b>
              </p>
              <p className="paragraph-151">
                Our technology provides you different options specialized in your
                needs
            </p>
              <div className="button">
                <button onClick={() => window.location.href = "/features"} className="btn-1">SEE ALL FEAUTURES</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="div-block-312">
            <img src={require("../../assets/img/vision.svg")} alt=""/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="div-block-83">
          <div className="section-77">
            <button className="btnT _1">FACIAL RECOGNITION</button>
            <button className="btnT">OBJECT DETECTION</button>
          </div>
          <div className="section-88">
            <ObjectD />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="section-91">
          <Form />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

export default Technologies

Los div hijos los tengo como componentes para solo mandarlos a llamar, lo que deseo hacer es que al momento de apretar un botón aparezca un div hijo y al apretar el otro botón aparezca el otro div hijo y desaparezca el anterior, me dijeron que ocupara switch true false pero no encuentro un ejemplo o una explicación en si que me ayude hacer esto.

Comment: Hola Daniel, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita tu pregunta para añadir un ejemplo de código más completo. El código compartido deja fuera partes que podrían ser importantes para solucionar el problema.

Comment: estas usando react hooks o react components? no veo ese DOM dentro de algun return

Comment: @BlackHole react componets, ahorita no he realizado ningun codigo por que ando perdido en eso, solo lo he maquetado y puesto los dos botones y los dos div que quiero que se muestren y oculten con cada boton

Comment: usa el `state` de react, que cada click al botton el estado con `this.setState()`, y ahi pones el switch o if en el dom con los componentes

Comment: @BlackHole gracias me funciono con el Switch y el this.setState()

Answer (score 0):

*Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, de casualidad en estos días me tropecé con un problema muy similar.*

*No cuento con lo necesario en tu código como para elaborarte una respuesta adecuada, pero sí te puedo adjuntar un ejemplo de cómo solucioné ese problema en mi proyecto.*

Lo que hice fue poner el componente a mostrar en el `state` e irlo cambiando según el componente a mostrar en determinado momento. Luego en el lugar donde quiero  mostrar el componente simplemente llamo a esa propiedad del state. Adjunto debajo el código de mi componente y con los comentarios puntuales, no dudes en comentar ante cualquier duda.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu, Breadcrumb, Icon } from 'antd';
import { GlobalStyleLayout } from './Styles';
import IconsLayout from './IconsLayout';
import Users from './Users';//este es un componente
import Register from './Register';//este es el otro componente

const { SubMenu } = Menu;
const { Header, Content, Sider } = Layout;

class LayoutComponent extends Component {

    state = {
        component: 'valor inicial'  //Esta es la propiedad del estado donde va a estar el componente que se muestra en el momento
    }

    changeComponent = (param) => {//esta es la funcion donde cambio de componente a mostrar
        this.setState({
            component: param
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <GlobalStyleLayout id="components-layout-demo-top-side-2">
                <Layout>
                    <Header className="header">
                        <div className="logo" />
                        <Menu
                            theme="dark"
                            mode="horizontal"
                            style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }}
                        >
                            {/* En estos items llamo a la funcion de cambiar el componente y le paso el mismo como paramatro */}
                            <Menu.Item onClick={() => this.changeComponent(<Users />)} key="1">Users</Menu.Item>
                            <Menu.Item onClick={() => this.changeComponent(<Register />)} key="2">Register</Menu.Item>
                            <Menu.Item key="3">nav 3</Menu.Item>
                            <IconsLayout />
                        </Menu>
                    </Header>
                    <Layout>
                        <Sider width={200} style={{ background: '#fff' }}>
                            <Menu
                                mode="inline"
                                defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
                                defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
                                style={{ height: '100%', borderRight: 0 }}
                            >
                                <SubMenu key="sub1" title={<span><Icon type="user" />subnav 1</span>}>
                                    <Menu.Item key="1">option1</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="2">option2</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="3">option3</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="4">option4</Menu.Item>
                                </SubMenu>
                                <SubMenu key="sub2" title={<span><Icon type="laptop" />subnav 2</span>}>
                                    <Menu.Item key="5">option5</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="6">option6</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="7">option7</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="8">option8</Menu.Item>
                                </SubMenu>
                                <SubMenu key="sub3" title={<span><Icon type="notification" />subnav 3</span>}>
                                    <Menu.Item key="9">option9</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="10">option10</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="11">option11</Menu.Item>
                                    <Menu.Item key="12">option12</Menu.Item>
                                </SubMenu>
                            </Menu>
                        </Sider>
                        <Layout style={{ padding: '0 24px 24px' }}>
                            <Breadcrumb style={{ margin: '16px 0' }}>
                                <Breadcrumb.Item>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
                                <Breadcrumb.Item>List</Breadcrumb.Item>
                                <Breadcrumb.Item>App</Breadcrumb.Item>
                            </Breadcrumb>
                            <Content style={{
                                background: '#fff', padding: 24, margin: 0, minHeight: 280,
                            }}
                            >
                                {/* En la siguiente linea llamo y muestro el componente almacenado en la propiedad corrrespondiente en el state */}
                                {this.state.component}
                            </Content>
                        </Layout>
                    </Layout>
                </Layout>
            </GlobalStyleLayout>
        );
    }
}

export default LayoutComponent;
```